# Changing caps lock to tab in Linux/Gnome 3.x

Tags: linux, keyboard, gnome, xorg.conf

I have (physically) broken my tab key and would need like to use the CAPS LOCK key as the tab key instead. I have tried to do this with xorg.conf

```
    Option "XkbOptions" "tab:swapcaps"
```

but it doesn't seem to have any effect (nor can I see any errors regarding this config in the logs).

Any help changing CAPS_LOCK to work as tab key would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

One can use xmodmap, I think this link gives enough information:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/94503/how-to-swap-remap-the-caps-lock-key-with-tab-key